# How to use sub in parameterizing in AWS CloudFormation?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, aws-cloudformation-custom-resource

```
{
   "AWSTemplateFormatVersion":"2010-09-09",
   "Parameters":{
      "Prefix":{
         "Type":"String",
         "Description":"Prefix to add to the names of the IAM resources",
         "Default":"my-prefix",
         "MinLength": "3",
         "MaxLength": "9",
         "ConstraintDescription": "Prefix must be between 3 and 9 characters in length and must be a String."
      }
   },
   "Resources":{
      "RkVpcPolicyGroup":{
         "Type":"AWS::IAM::Group",
         "Properties":{
            "GroupName":{
               "!Sub":"${Prefix}-evpc-policy-group"
            }
         }
      },
      "RkVpcEksctlPolicyGroup":{
         "Type":"AWS::IAM::Group",
         "Properties":{
            "GroupName":{
               "!Sub":"${Prefix}-evpc-eksctl-policy-group"
            }
         }
      },
      "RkExistingVpcServiceAccountUser":{
         "Type":"AWS::IAM::User",
         "Properties":{
            "UserName":{
               "!Sub":"${Prefix}-existing-vpc-sa"
            },
            "Groups":[
               {
                  "Ref":"RkVpcPolicyGroup"
               },
               {
                  "Ref":"RkVpcEksctlPolicyGroup"
               }
            ]
         }
      }
   }
}
```

I have tried using sub function in adding a prefix to my IAM resources names but the above the code throwing "Value of property GroupName must be of type String" error for both logicalID's RkVpcEksctlPolicyGroup and RkVpcPolicyGroup. What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1):

You should use **full form** of `Sub`. Thus for `RkVpcPolicyGroup` it should be:

```
      "RkVpcPolicyGroup":{
         "Type":"AWS::IAM::Group",
         "Properties":{
            "GroupName":{
               "Fn::Sub":["${Prefix}-evpc-policy-group", {"Prefix": {"Ref": "Prefix"}}]
            }
         }
      }
```

Similar changes have to be done for the other group.

Comment: Do I need to do the same for other logical IDs as well?

Comment: @ManikantaReddy Yes, for other places where you get error with `GroupName`.

Comment: @ManikantaReddy How did it go? Is it still unclear what you should do?